# ast.literal_eval() method truncates float value while converting str to dict

Tags: python, string, pandas

Here I am trying convert dict to string using `ast` module. I found that the values are truncated as shown in the output below. how can I get a atual value without truncation here.

**code**

```
df = DataFrame({
            'a': np.random.randn(6),
            'b':['foo','bar']*3,
            'c':np.random.randn(6)
            })
mapping = df.to_dict() 
d=str(mapping)
e= ast.literal_eval(d)
print mapping
print;print e
```

**output**

`{'a': {0: 0.88241526852727104, 1: -0.062779346232699929, 2: -0.058427377402568821, 3: 0.87157579927705897, 4: -1.0399255501591143, 5: 0.11203584043469664}, 'c': {0: 0.56763771194925394, 1: 0.22824054879261255, 2: -0.58324477854217549, 3: -0.2264734421572463, 4: 0.45754374820401839, 5: 1.35849692636584}, 'b': {0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', 2: 'foo', 3: 'bar', 4: 'foo', 5: 'bar'}}`
`

`{'a': {0: 0.882415268527271, 1: -0.06277934623269993, 2: -0.05842737740256882, 3: 0.871575799277059, 4: -1.0399255501591143, 5: 0.11203584043469664}, 'c': {0: 0.5676377119492539, 1: 0.22824054879261255, 2: -0.5832447785421755, 3: -0.2264734421572463, 4: 0.4575437482040184, 5: 1.35849692636584}, 'b': {0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', 2: 'foo', 3: 'bar', 4: 'foo', 5: 'bar'}}`

Comment: It is the *`str(mapping)` call* that truncates the values, not the `ast.literal_eval()` parsing (which is really just the Python syntax parser producing an abstract parse tree, which is then used to produce Python values). What are you trying to do; serialise the data? There are better formats for that.

Comment: I dont think `str(mapping)` call truncates the values I have checked that.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` interprets the string **exactly as would a float literal be interpreted in Python code**. It doesn't truncate *anything*. `str()` on a dictionary on the other hand, triggers `repr()` calls on float values, which most certainly *does* simplify float values.

Comment: But you ignored my question. **What are you trying to do, really**.

Comment: I am trying to encrypt all the float values of the data frames with a key. I am experimenting with a encryption which gives numeric string as a cipher to numeric text. In a nutshell I am trying to make a decoy of a dataframe as an encrypted dataframe

Comment: Then why not try and talk about that? There are probably better ways to do that than to turn your data into a string with `str()`.

Comment: In above code I get identical values to `print mapping` and `print str(mapping)`

Comment: why not use json.dumps(mapping)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham similar is the case with json.dumps

Comment: @ceasif. how does the output differ?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham output to values differ in exactly same way as above case

Comment: @ceasif what python version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is simply the type, not the value. `numpy.float64` often uses more precision than needed to represent a float on printing, and represents it exactly. Python's `float` type gives the most precision needed to have the value round correctly on conversion to float.

If you want it to be the original dictionary, you'll have to convert the floats to `numpy.float64`s.

```
type(DataFrame({0: [0.88241526852727104]}).to_dict()[0][0])
#>>> <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

```
float64(0.882415268527271)
#>>> 0.88241526852727104

float64(0.88241526852727104)
#>>> 0.88241526852727104

0.88241526852727104
#>>> 0.882415268527271

float64(0.88241526852727104) == 0.88241526852727104
#>>> True

float(float64(0.88241526852727104)) == 0.88241526852727104
#>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type using simplejson:

```
mapping = df.to_dict()
import simplejson as json
a_str = json.dumps(mapping)
a_dict=json.loads(a_str,parse_float=np.float64)
```

The output should match using that.

[simplejson](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)